# Customizing bootstrap primary color causing side effects by changing font color - scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to change the primary color in bootstrap to be the color #458AF7, which is a softer shade of blue. But when I use the following code, the color of the text in the button goes from being white, which is the default for a primary button in bootstrap to black despite the fact that I did not change the color property or any other variables in my custom.scss.

custom.scss

```
$primary: #458AF7;
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';  // bootstrap's main scss file
```

App.js

```
import ./custom.scss
```

I expected only the button background-color to change, but not the color of the text.

Comment: I suspect it's this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#color-contrast